# How to evaluate the following integral may be related to the incomplete gamma function?

Tags: definite-integrals, gamma-function, mellin-transform

\begin{align}
& \int_{0}^{\infty}y^{\nu-1}e^{-y}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x}(\alpha x+y)^{\beta}dxdy\\
=& \int_{0}^{\infty}y^{\nu-1}e^{-y}(\alpha^{\beta}e^{\frac{y}{\alpha}}\Gamma(\beta+1,\frac{y}{\alpha}))dy,\quad (3)
\end{align}
where $\Gamma(\cdot,\cdot)$ represents the upper incomplete gamma function, i.e., $\Gamma(s,x)=\int_{x}^{\infty}t^{s-1}e^{-t}dt$.

If I can find a compact form of the above integral (3) ?

Thanks a lot, Liu.

Comment: You even did not tell the signs or bounds of $(\alpha,\beta,\nu)$ which makes that the first integral could be not correct. Please precise

Comment: Being optimistic, I suppose that the end result *could be* a Gaussian hypergeometric function.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Claude!

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici  I'm sorry to bother you ! But if you could help me with the following integral ? The link is as follows :  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4480001/1063306   Thanks a lot, Liu.

Comment: I have no idea for this other problem. Sorry for that

Comment: Thanks a lot, Liu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

Given real parameters $\left(\beta,\nu,a\right)\in\mathbb{R}^{3}$, suppose

$$0<\beta+\nu+1\land0<\nu\land\left[0<a\lor\left(a=0\land0<\beta+\nu\right)\right].$$

These are the most general conditions for which the following integral is convergent and real-valued:

$$\mathcal{I}{\left(\beta,\nu,a\right)}=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}y\,y^{\nu-1}e^{-y}\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\left(ax+y\right)^{\beta}e^{-x}.$$

Changing the order of integration and rescaling the integrals in the right way, the double integral in question turns out to be separable. We obtain

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}{\left(\beta,\nu,a\right)}
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}y\,y^{\nu-1}e^{-y}\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\left(ax+y\right)^{\beta}e^{-x}\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}y\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\left(ax+y\right)^{\beta}e^{-x}y^{\nu-1}e^{-y}\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}y\,\left(ax+y\right)^{\beta}y^{\nu-1}e^{-x-y}\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}t\,x\,\left(ax+xt\right)^{\beta}(xt)^{\nu-1}e^{-x-xt};~~~\small{\left[y=xt\right]}\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}t\,\left(a+t\right)^{\beta}x^{\beta+\nu}t^{\nu-1}e^{-x(1+t)}\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}t\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,t^{\nu-1}\left(a+t\right)^{\beta}x^{\beta+\nu}e^{-(1+t)x}\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{t^{\nu-1}\left(a+t\right)^{\beta}}{\left(1+t\right)^{\beta+\nu+1}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}u\,u^{\beta+\nu}e^{-u};~~~\small{\left[x=\frac{u}{1+t}\right]}\\
&=\Gamma{\left(\beta+\nu+1\right)}\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{t^{\nu-1}\left(a+t\right)^{\beta}}{\left(1+t\right)^{\beta+\nu+1}};~~~\small{\left[-1<\beta+\nu\right]}\\
&=\nu^{-1}\Gamma{\left(\beta+\nu+1\right)}\,{_2F_1}{\left(-\beta,1;\nu+1;1-a\right)},\\
\end{align}$$

where in the last line above we've made use of [this integral representation](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/07/01/01/0002/) variant for the Gauss hypergeometric function.

---

Comment: Thanks a lot, David  ! I'll try my best to understand it!

Comment: David, I'm sorry to bother you again. If I calculate the above integral, then how can I solve the integral in the following link ?   https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4471443/1063306   Or if I could calculate it in another way? The $T$, $\rho_{d},\mathrm{n}_{d}$ are all integers and $2\leq T\leq 84$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, David!

Comment: @LZ981ko Yikes! I’ll take another look after I’ve had some sleep, but I doubt I’ll be able to solve that integral. Best of luck. =/

Comment: @ Thanks a Lot, David ! Have a good dream ! Sleep tight!

Comment: Hey, David! I'm sorry to bother you, recently I modified the question I raised earlier and found that the integral may need to be estimated can be converted into the following form.  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4480001/1063306      I adopted a possible scaling method of Bessel function. I wonder if this is reasonable?  Any useful suggestion is welcome, Liu.